# Getting always IllegalStateException error when trying to obtain bitmap from view

Tags: android, bitmap, android-graphview

I am trying to obtain the bitmap from a GraphView in order to not generate twice the same graph. I am continously getting the the following error (despite having the hardwareAccelerated=true):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GraphView must be used in hardware accelerated mode.You can use android:hardwareAccelerated="true" on your activity
```

-Here is the code where I try to do this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(graphView.getWidth(), graphView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Drawable bgDrawable = graphView.getBackground();
            if (bgDrawable != null) {
                bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
            } else {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            graphView.draw(canvas);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I've tried several things but no one with sucess. I've tried even to put the graphView inside a layout and get the bitmap from the layout but this didn't worked either (i get exactly the same error).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920458/getting-illegalstateexception-when-trying-to-take-snapshot-of-the-graph-for-http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(graphView.getWidth(),graphView.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap){

                @Override
                public boolean isHardwareAccelerated(){
                    return true;
                }
            };

            graphView.draw(canvas);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
<activity ... />
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
```

in the manifest file of yours.

Comment: I have hardwareAccelerated=true in the app

Comment: well its for the activity have you done this in activity also? and one thing more are you using the external library?